# Vlookup with Multiple conditions with a drop down list already created

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Good day,

I have a raw data set with the following raw data set wit the following filters:
`Wealth Type`, 'Institution', 'State/Province', Personality', 'Income Band', 'No of clients'

I need to create a vlookup formula based on a drop down list that I've already created:

1. State/Province
2. Personality
3. Income Band

From these three drop down lists, it needs pull through the number of clients from a vlookup formula that fit each of the three criteria listed above.

I have tried a standard vlookup formula but that only works based off of one criteria.

Comment: Use `FILTER()` function instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array formula combining `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions to achieve VLOOKUP-like functionality with multiple criteria.

```
=INDEX('Raw Data'!F:F, MATCH(1, ('Raw Data'!A:A=DropDown1)*('Raw Data'!B:B=DropDown2)*('Raw Data'!C:C=DropDown3), 0))
```

Just replace `'Raw Data'!F:F`, `'Raw Data'!A:A`, etc. with actual ranges and `DropDown1`, `DropDown2`, `DropDown3` with cell references where you have the drop-down lists. Enter this formula as an array formula by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.